# Working with two lots of columns using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using the following query to select wait times from the table `wait_times` where the user id is 1 and then select the venue's information that has the id of the wait time's venue id.

```
SELECT w . * , v . *
FROM  `wait_times` AS  `w` 
INNER JOIN  `venues` AS  `v` ON  `v`.id =  `w`.venue_id
WHERE w.user_id =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However, when I perform this query, as I have columns named `user_id` and `id` in both tables, I received two lots of values for each column name. Please can you tell me how I make these values distinguishable, and rename them to 'table_name.columnname' respectively so that they can be easily recognised?

Comment: Can't you just select all the columns individually, just excluding the `id` or `user_id` column, instead of using wildcards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be:

```
SELECT w.colum1 as name1, w.colum2 as name2, w.*, v.colum1 as name3, v.colum2 as name4, v.*
FROM  `wait_times` AS  `w` 
INNER JOIN  `venues` AS  `v` ON  `v`.id =  `w`.venue_id
WHERE w.user_id =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Just allocate the colums which have the same name a (temporary) different name.

Comment: So you could access colum1-4 via name1, name2, name3 and name4. Also you can still access the other colums (if they already have a unique name).

Comment: Ok, would it be possible to remove the columns once renamed?

Comment: what do you mean with remove? basically you can now access the colums with their alternative name. for instance in php you could have something like: while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($dbquery)) { echo $row->name1; } (you don't use the real column name. instead you use the alternative one)